# Compile error on while loop

Tags: c++, compilation

I can't get the code to compile because of the last part of the code in which I want the program to ask if the user would like to continue and use the program again. Any help would be appreciated I am a beginner thanks!
    # include 
    using namespace std;

```
//function prototype
void input(double &feet, double &inches);
void conversion(double feet, double &inches, int &meters, double &centimeters);
void output(int meters, double centimeters);   

void main() //Input Function
{
    //declaring variables
    int meters;         //declaring meters
    double feet,        //declaring feet
        inches,      //declaring inches
        centimeters; //declaring centimeters


                        //loop

    {   
        input(feet, inches);           //function
        conversion(feet, inches, meters, centimeters); //function
        output(meters, centimeters);  //function
    }

}

void input(double &feet, double &inches)
{
    cout << "Enter number of feet: ";
    cin >> feet;
    while (feet < 0) {
        cout << "ERROR. Please enter a positive value for feet.";
        cout << "\nEnter number of feet: ";
        cin >> feet;
    }
    cout << "Enter number of inches: ";
    cin >> inches;
    while (inches < 0) {
        cout << "ERROR. Please enter a positive value for inches.";
        cout << "\nEnter number of inches: ";
        cin >> inches;
    }
}

void conversion(double feet, double &inches, int &meters, double &centimeters)
{
    inches += 12 * feet;
    centimeters = inches * 2.54;
    meters = centimeters / 100;
    centimeters -= meters * 100;
}

void output(int meters, double centimeters)
{
    char menu;

    cout << meters << " meter(s) and " << centimeters << " centimeters " << endl;
    cout << "Continue(Y/N) ";
    cin >> menu;
} while (menu == 'Y' || menu == 'y');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a `do-while` loop there. You're missing `do`.

Comment: I also tried that but probably did it wrong I get 2 errors with my do-while loop return value doesnt match function type and also 'output' 'void' function returning a value this is how i did the do-while loop                 void output(int meters, double centimeters)
{
 char menu;
 
 cout << meters << " meter(s) and " << centimeters << " centimeters " << endl; 
 do{
  cout << "Continue(Y/N): ";
  cin >> menu;
 } while (menu == 'Y' || menu == 'y');
 return 0;
}

Comment: You shouldn't have `return 0;` in a `void` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one comment poitned out. You were missing `do{`  I added a `cin.ignore();` as well.

```
do{    
        cout << meters << " meter(s) and " << centimeters << " centimeters " << endl;
        cout << "Continue(Y/N) ";
        cin >> menu;
        cin.ignore();  //i think if you press enter it will add white space.
    } while (menu == 'Y' || menu == 'y');
```

Edit: The loop will continue running where you placed the  { } so you should find a better place to put it. I placed it in your main. This should fix your issue.

```
do{
        input(feet, inches);           //function
        conversion(feet, inches, meters, centimeters); //function
        output(meters, centimeters);  //function
            cout << "Continue(Y/N) ";
            cin >> menu;
 } while (menu == 'Y' || menu == 'y');
```

Comment: That worked! The only problem with it is when you put 'Y' instead of allowing you to reenter the ft and inches for conversion it just reprints the previous result how can I fix that?

Comment: still runs the same :(

Comment: @jackblack if it worked mark it as a solution. also, read this to learn more about do-while loops https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_do_while_loop.htm